# Iterator inside state function coming as Empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, dataset, streaming

I have case classes like these. And I am generating test data using RateStreamSource. It is giving me a Dataset. Now I am grouping the dataset `groupByKey` and call `mapGroupsWithState`.

However inside the state function `updateRateAnother` there is some logic and I am printing the iterator. The Iterator always comes as Empty in the method and my logic does not work.

Following is the minimum reproducible example of the code

```
case class Employee(id: String, value: Long)
case class Rate(timestamp: Timestamp, value: Long)
case class Rate2(timestamp: Timestamp, value: Long, age: Int)

object ResourceConfigConsolidator {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

       val sparkSession = SparkSession
                         .builder()
                         .appName("TestJob")
                         .getOrCreate()

      import sparkSession.implicits._
      val rate = 2
      val randoms = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
      def randomElement = Random.shuffle(randoms).head
      val rcConfigDS = sparkSession
                        .readStream
                        .format("rate") // <-- use RateStreamSource
                        .option("rowsPerSecond", rate)
                        .load()
                        .as[Rate].filter(_.value % 40 == 0).map {
                          r => Rate2(r.timestamp, r.value, randomElement)
                        }


 def updateRateAnother(key: Int, values: Iterator[Rate2], state: 
                              GroupState[Employee]): Option[Employee] = {
     println("key is here ::" + key)
     if (state.hasTimedOut) {
    // We've timed out, lets extract the state and send it down the stream
    state.remove()
    state.getOption
  } else {
    println("the iterating values ::::" + values.toList.mkString(" , \n"))
    println("hello length ::::" + values.length)
    if (!state.exists) {
      if (values.length == 0) {
        None
      } else {
        val latestValue = values.toList.maxBy(_.value)
        val employee = Employee(latestValue.value.toString, latestValue.value)
        state.update(employee)
        Some(employee)
      }
    } else {
      if (values.isEmpty) {
        val currentState = state.get
        Some(currentState)
      } else {
        val latestValue = values.toList.maxBy(_.value)
        val currentState = state.get
        val updated = currentState.copy(latestValue.value.toString, latestValue.value)
        state.update(currentState.copy(latestValue.value.toString, latestValue.value))
        Some(updated)
       }
     }
    }
   }

  val res: Dataset[Employee] = rcConfigDS.groupByKey(_.age).
  mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.NoTimeout())(updateRateAnother).flatMap(emp => 
  emp)

  res.writeStream.format("console")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
  .option("truncate", value = false)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint1")
  .start()

 }
}
```

Since I am grouping with the `age`, there should be at least one object in the iterator . Am I right in saying this ? Why is the iterator coming as empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is empty *when you print it*? Because that's the only thing that is surprising. You can only go through an iterator once, so once you do `values.toList` for the first time, it *becomes empty*. You should assign result of `toList` to a variable, and discard the iterator.

Better yet, change your logic so that you only need one pass, and get rid of `toList` (you can call `maxBy` on `Iterator` directly ... but only once). The idea is to not load all data at once into memory when dealing with a large dataset.